# Setting Y position to px in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm setting up a sticky nav table of contents on the left of my page to scroll with the page and I'm using Jquery to have it scroll down with the page. I have the position in absolute position 150px from top, but when I am using Jquery it requires the nav to hit the top of the page than will jump down to the top:150px position but how can I get it to activate once it reaches 150px away from the top so there is no longer the jump.

You can view this at http://stormable.com/heroes/malfurion/

If you notice when you scroll up the jump links on the right side have to hit the top of the page before it activates the fixed position.

I'm assuming I have to change the y >= top in the script but I'm not exactly sure how to change it to activate at say 150px from the top.

The Jquery I'm using is

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    var top = $('#jump-list').offset().top - parseFloat($('#jump-list').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        // what the y position of the scroll is
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        // whether that's below the form
        if (y >= top) {
          // if so, ad the fixed class
          $('#jump-list').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
          // otherwise remove it
          $('#jump-list').removeClass('fixed');
        }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just change the top var to:

```
 var top = $('#jump-list').offset().top - 100
```

Comment: Thank you, it still has a tiny bit of a jump to it, is that fixable or no?